# Cannot afford speeding ticket Netherlands

Tags: speeding, netherlands

My friend lives in the Netherlands and was doing 62 km/h in a 30 km/h zone.
He did this on a scooter that he illegally removed the 25 km/h cap on.
From these two facts the fine will likely be around 400 euros, which he cannot afford.

Is there any way for him to pay it off with community service or in monthly payments?

Are there any ways he can pay for his mistake without crippling him financially and putting him in debt?

Comment: Sell the scooter?

Comment: Lucky the fines in the Netherlands are so low - in Australia this would set you back almost $2,000 and your licence

Comment: Selling the scooter is sadly not a solution. Since he removed the speed cap on the scooter it is not street legal. Making it street legal would cost 800 euros alone. And it will likely only sell for around 500.

Comment: Slightly strange phrasing - he will be in debt the moment the fine is pronounced. Debts to the government typically take precedence over such trivialities as eating, but the court *may* allow staged payment; either consult a lawyer or explain your financial situation and throw yourself on the mercy of the court.

Comment: 400 Euros only is cheap, considering a massive violation of the speed limit, driving a vehicle that is not road safe, driving without license (unless he has a motorbike license), and driving without insurance.

Comment: @TimLymington your second sentence seems rather hyperbolic.  I don't know any country in which the government would actually enforce fines to the extent that someone would starve as a result.  (I don't deny that such countries might exist, but the Netherlands is surely not one of them.)

Comment: @phoog; possibly poor phrasing. Whatever government policy is on enforcement, a debt to the government takes precedence over other sums owed. If you die or go bankrupt, the person handling your estate will 1) pay fines and taxes 2) pay other legitimate debts and 3) consult your wishes about the surplus. In some circumstances a trustee will in step 2 allow you to keep your tools and car - if and only the resulting employment will allow creditors to receive more later.

Comment: @TimLymington bankruptcy laws I'm familiar with include explicit protections for assets and income needed to continue housing and feeding oneself and one's family.  I'm unaware of any such protections being waived in the case of a government-imposed fine.  In the Netherlands, bankruptcies explicitly exclude "bed and bedding" of the debtor, as well as any tools of trade.  The obvious reason for this is that bankruptcy is not to deprive bankrupt parties of the means to feed, clothe, and house themselves and their families.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked for a link to the CJIB pages on paying fines in monthly bits. It is here: https://www.cjib.nl/betalen-delen-aanvragen-voor-een-verkeersboete.
He will  have to make a request for such an arrangement at the CJIB himself. It will depend on what type of communication he has received from the authorities, and how quickly he responds to it.